# Grammar and use of 'as we know it'

Tags: idioms

In my understanding, '[as we know it](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20we%20know%20it)' usually follows a noun phrase and means like

- The building as we know it = the version/condition of the building we know now.

First, I'm not sure about its grammar.

- Is the 'as' a conjunction?
- Is it correct to think that 'it' changes to 'them'? E.g., the buildings as we know them

Second, a question about its use.

- Is it possible to use when the preceding noun is a pronoun? If yes, what should the 'it' be changed to?

I feel *Tom as I knew him ten years ago* will be understood. I'm not sure about *He as I knew him*, and even less sure about the case of second person pronoun. For example, if I want to say 'You have change a lot', is it possible to say like *You are so different from you as I knew you*?

---

I guess a more usual way to express the last sentence above would be *You are so different from the person I knew you were*. If this works, what happens if I'm talking to plural you? Making *person* plural (*...from the people I knew you were*) looks a bit strange to me.

Comment: Yes, _as we know it_ can be inflected to suit the situation (_as I knew him_ and so on), but I think the most natural way to express  your sentence would be _You are so different from the person/Tom I used to know_.

Comment: @KateBunting I see, even then, would you say *You guys are different from the **people** I used to know*?

Comment: Yes, you can. It's a common construction, but it's not a fixed phrase, so its parts can be inflected normally. OTOH, if some particular way of doing that sounds weird to you, don't say it -- trust your internal grammar; it actually knows all the rules, even if you can't state them consciously. The way it raises a flag is to make it feel weird, so pay attention.

Answer (score 1):

*As* in this context serves to introduce a comparative clause.

> [the building [as [we know it]]]

The comparative clause has a meaning close to:

> We know it *to be this way*.

This is not a set phrase, so all the words can inflect or be swapped out depending on the context.

> the **buildings** as we know **them**
>
> the building as we **knew** it
>
> the building as **I** knew it
>
> the building as **he imagined** it
>
> etc.

This means that the phrase 'as we know it' is not in fact an idiom - it can be readily understood from its component words and their normal grammatical relations in English.

Though ***as*** can be found assigned to the nebulous 'conjunction' category in many dictionaries and older grammars, it's best categorized as a preposition and is thusly categorized by respected modern grammars such as the *Oxford Modern English Grammar* and the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*.

As far as using that phrase or any phrase headed by a preposition following a pronoun, it would have to be read as a supplement, and would usually be set off by a comma:

> He, as I knew him then, would never have accepted a bribe.

An attested example:

> New "successions" will take place; the changing Many will pass
> endlessly on in its phantom army, for ever appearing, and forever
> falling back into the One: but he, as we knew him, will awake no more,
> ah, nevermore! (SUGGESTIONS LITERARY ESSAYS; Ernest Edward Kellett; 1929)

This is a rather rare usage though, and perhaps better avoided in everyday writing.